# How would I connect two HTML pseudo element lines with another vertical pseudo line, spanning table rows?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I'm attempting to connect paired bootstrap labels that exist in an HTML table.  Each pair consists of an "In" and an "Out" color-matched label that will represent a patient's entry into, and exit out of, a care facility.  The pair may or may not be contained on a single table row.  Please see the attached snippet for what I have cooking so far.

Please also see [my mock-up of the desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebYTs.jpg).

I'm using pseudo elements to render the horizontal connecting lines, and this seems to play well when resizing the window.  So far I'm happy with the results.  But now I'm finding it challenging to add vertical connecting lines to complete the path.

I've gone through a few messy iterations using pseudo elements to draw in the vertical line, but with undesirable results.  My experience with pseudo elements is minimal, so any help or suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks!

```css
.admit-discharge-cell {
  width: 100px;
}
.admit-in-label { 
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 1em;
 position: relative
}
.admit-out-label { 
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 1em;
 position: relative
}
.admit-in-label::after {
 content: '';
 width: 1em;
 border-bottom: 1px solid;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
}
.admit-out-label::before {
 content: '';
 width: 1em;
 border-bottom: 1px solid;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: -1em;
 right: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

<table class="table table-striped">
 <tr>
  <td>03/01/2018</td>
  <td>04/28/2018</td>
  <td class="admit-discharge-cell">
      <div class="pull-right admit-out-label"><span class="label label-info" data-direction="out">Out</span></div>
  </td>
  <td>Some Data</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>02/24/2018</td>
  <td>03/01/2018</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>Some Data</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>02/10/2018</td>
  <td>02/24/2018</td>
  <td>
      <div class="pull-left admit-in-label"><span class="label label-info" data-direction="in">In</span></div>
  </td>
  <td>Some Data</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>02/23/2017</td>
  <td>03/03/2017</td>
  <td>
   <div class="pull-left admit-in-label"><span class="label label-primary" data-direction="in">In</span></div>
      <div class="pull-right admit-out-label"><span class="label label-primary" data-direction="out">Out</span></div>
  </td>
  <td>Some Data</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>02/20/2016</td>
  <td>02/26/2016</td>
  <td>
   <div class="pull-left admit-in-label"><span class="label label-info" data-direction="in">In</span></div>
      <div class="pull-right admit-out-label"><span class="label label-info" data-direction="out">Out</span></div>
  </td>
  <td>Some Data</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If these vertical connectors are going to be different sizes, this won't work without some JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you have to tidy up the lines so they're touching. They have margins and floats that are conflicting. Also using `em` for your margins here is going to create unpredictable results. Most likely you'll have to use precise `px` measurements to make sure the horizontal lines touch.

For the vertical lines, you can't do this with CSS alone. Even if you created an invisible vertical div for every possible connecting combination you'd still need Javascript to turn the right ones "on." With Javascript you'll have to calculate the x,y coordinates of the two points you want to connect than add the vertical div with absolute positioning over them.

EDIT: If you know the table row heights, there might be a way to create the connector div on top of the first origin point, horizontally first, then rotating it 90 degrees on the origin point. Again you'd need JS to do this.

Comment: Correct, I do have a bit of tweaking to do.  And I'll also switch from em to px for measurements.  Continuing, I did have some success with using pseudo elements for the vertical lines when I broke segments up into individual sections that did not traverse table row boundaries.  i.e. each table cell would have its own pseudo element.  No javascript used yet.  [Here](https://imgur.com/egwdZ2X) is a screenshot of my progress.  It's crude, as I'm still playing around to see if this is even viable. Generally, it's the sort of thing I'm looking for, but is starting to feel a bit hacky and fragile.